# Exactly once delivery end to end with pulsar and flink

Tags: apache-flink, apache-pulsar

I am trying to use flink with pulsar. The pulsar will act as a source and sink. I am looking for an exactly once delivery guarantee for this solution.

I have  read about flink two phase commit implementation with kafka and I could not find a equivalent for pulsar.  https://flink.apache.org/features/2018/03/01/end-to-end-exactly-once-apache-flink.html

Also I have looked at the pulsar producer for flink it does not support exactly once guarantee.

https://github.com/apache/pulsar/blob/master/pulsar-flink/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/pulsar/PulsarProduceMode.java

I would appreciate any pointers on how to achieve end to end exactly once delivery with pulsar flink combination.